# How to make a route both for get and post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this:

```
resources :users do

  collection do


  get 'blah'

  end

end
```

I want to make this action (blah) for both post and get now, possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just enter the same name for the post route like this:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'blah'
    post 'blah'
  end
end
```

Both routes will have the same controller, action and url_helpers

Comment: thanks that's what I did but I thought there was a way to do it with a single line.

Comment: does "any 'blah'" work? (a guess, since the old style routes used 'blah' => :get, 'blah' => :post, 'blah' => :any)

Comment: It is not mentioned in the docs and I did a quick look through the source and could only find the methods get, post, put, delete and redirect. So it does not look like "any" would work

Answer (score 11):

Looks like [verb constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) is what you want.

```
match 'blah', to: 'users#blah', via: [:get, :post]
```

or

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'blah', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```